# How to display in a select field html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `select` tag and I want to display picture on left of every `option`

What I tried is that

```
<select>
    <option value="1">
        <div>
            <img src="some source img-circle" height="25" weight="25" style="float: left" /> Name 1 
        </div>
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        <div>
            <img src="some source img-circle" height="25" weight="25" style="float: left" /> Name 1 
        </div>
    </option>
</select>
```

But this displays nothing, I also tried to put `div` outside of `option` tag. Please tell me how to

Output should be like

```
(image) My Name
```

Comment: You can only put text in option tags as the docs say: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Forgot that `::before` will not work on a `select` - this approach will work, but you'll need to add it to a div placed as a parent to the select:

```
<div class="with-image">
  <select>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This does not work because `div` cannot be a child of `option`. You can achieve this using CSS:

```
select::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(image.jpg);
}
```

This will add a pseudo element, which is a good thing because the image does not need to be added directly to each select in your HTML.

**Update 2**: If the image is loaded dynamically this approach can still work, with a minor alteration:

```
<div class="select-image">
  <span class="user-image" style="background-image: url(dynamic-url.jpg)"></span>
  <select>...</select>
</div>
```

Then use CSS to style the span:

span.user-image {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Now this is going to be an issue. The options are iterated through foreach loop and every option is a user and every user has different picture. if I use css background then image would be same for every node

Comment: I would still use CSS for this - the background image fetches a url, you could set that as an inline style - I'll update my post.

Comment: Yeah use foreach to explain a bit. I am a backend engineer and learning this designing thing

Comment: Updated - this is the way I would implement this for dynamic images.

Comment: I got it! Thanks mate. I got the idea I can do it from here thanks a lot mate